# how to split rows based on separator in csv file in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split row based on separator but I am not able to get right result. Can someone help me how to do this?

Example:

```
df1:

rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   
R162       2.3               1
R162       2.3.1             1
R162       2.6               2
R162       2.6.1             2
R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3
```

Expected Result:

```
df2:

rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   comb_fld_order_1
R162       2.3               1                 1
R162       2.3.1             1                 1
R162       2.6               2                 2
R162       2.6.1             2                 2
R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3         3.2
R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3         3.1
R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3         3
```

I am writing this code for generating df1:

```
conn = redshift_conn()
cur = conn.cursor()
query = '''select rule_id,priority_order,comb_fld_order from medaff.imedical_business_rules_metadata  WHERE RULE_ID='R162' and comb_fld_order is not null order by priority_order'''
cur.execute(query)
res = cur.fetchall()
column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=column_names)
```

Comment: Please show also the content of your input file (and how you read it so far).

Comment: @Valdi_Bo Hi.. I am running the query - select rule_id,priority_order,comb_fld_order from medaff.imedical_business_rules_metadata  WHERE RULE_ID='R162' and comb_fld_order is not null order by priority_order

Comment: and creating a dataframe

Comment: Can you please write the code and input file content

Comment: what version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: The question doesn't include any attempt to solve the problem. [Try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please show what you've tried and any specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For more information [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue right now.
I've solved it with [`pandas.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: Please provide an example.